# How do you concatenate charts in Altair but have the charts in page position on the page?

Tags: python, visualization, dashboard, streamlit, altair

I want to make a dashboard within Streamlit using the Altair library. The interactive feature of clicking on  one graph and having that affecting another is really useful, however Altair is pretty restricitve on where I can place these graphs.

Are there any methods to have the graphs located anywhere on the page but still have the interactive link between them?

Right now I just have them either horizontally or vertically concatenated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you would have to add some filler like an empty chart or modify the css direclty maybe